# Native App Registration with AZ Powershell Module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, registration, nativeapplication

I need to register a native app on Azure Active Directory using the AZ Powershell 6 Module.
A native app can be registered with the command New-AzureADApplication in the AzureAD module setting the value of the field "PublicClient" to true, but the module AzureAD is not supported for powershell 6.

In powershell 6 it seems that the corresponding command is New-AzADApplication, which allows to register a Web app / API but not a native app.

So how is it possible to register a native app with the module AZ in powershell 6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not to support to use `Az` to create a native app directly. Azure has released a preview version of AzureAD module named [`AzureAD.Standard.Preview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#preview-version-of-azuread-module) which supports `Powershell Core 6`, this module provides the same functionality as `AzureAD`. You could use it like the `AzureAD` to create the native app.

PowerShell Gallery: https://www.poshtestgallery.com/packages/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD.Standard.Preview
```

For more details, see : [Azure AD PowerShell module with support for PowerShell Core](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2339/azure-ad-powershell-module-with-support-for-powershell-core).

Answer (score 2):

If you try `Install-Module -Name AzureAD.Standard.Preview` you will receive the following error:

```bsh
"PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'AzureAD.Standard.Preview'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\program files\powershell\6\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:9491 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage"
```

So you have to add the repository with the following command:

```
PS> Register-PSRepository -Name PreviewRepository -SourceLocation 'https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v1'
```

Then install and import the module

```
PS> Install-Module -Name AzureAD.Standard.Preview
PS> Import-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
```

Check the module is correctly installed and all the commands are imported.

```
PS> Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

Remember to call `Connect-AzureAD` always before `Login-AzAccount` or you will receive an error.

Thanks to Joy Wang and best regards.

Comment: AzureAD.Standard.Preview version 0.1.599.7 does not have cmdlet `Connect-AzureAD` in its exported commands. List: `((Get-Module 'AzureAD.Standard.Preview').ExportedCommands).Keys`