# Is there a Set-AzureADApplication equivalent in Az module?

Tags: azure-powershell

Currently I am using Set-AzureADApplication (from AzureAD module) with -RequiredResourceAccess option to set the access to the resources I need, I am converting my script to Az module however the closest thing I found to Set-AzureADApplication was Update-AzADApplication however it does not have a -RequiredResourceAccess option.

Is there an Az module that let's me update the azure app in a similar way as Set-AzureADApplication?

Thank you!

Comment: This probably not the answer you want, but it can be done via az cli.  There are several posts out there discussing the shortcoming of the Update-AzADApplication cmdlet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385802/how-to-give-azure-ad-application-access-to-required-permissions-using-powershell

Comment: You can also use the Microsoft API, but I'd stick with the az cli, it's easier. http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7197

Comment: I agree on @ScottHeath comments.. good way to update the permission...

Comment: So why you want to use the `Az` module instead of `AzureAD` module? Cross-platform issue? You are using powershell core?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such parameter like `-RequiredResourceAccess` for you to set the API permission in `Az` powershell module.

The one way is to use the azure cli [`az ad app permission add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-add) as mentioned in the comment.

Actually, if you want to fix the cross-platform issue with Powershell (I am not sure, but I don't think there will be a reason except this one), you could try the [powershell core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-6), it is cross-platform, refer to the [link1](https://blogs.endjin.com/2019/05/how-to-use-the-azuread-module-in-powershell-core/) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55187768/9455659) to install [`AzureAD.Standard.Preview`](https://www.poshtestgallery.com/packages/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.0.0.10) module which supports `AzureAD` commands.